# Executar 2 querys ou mais

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Queria executar 2 *queries* em C# quando o botão for clicado, mas só consigo executar uma.

```
public static void excluireventos()
{
    string connectionString = Conn.tank();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = string.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE Active" + "TRUNCATE TABLE Active_Number");
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Globals.UpdateLogs("Todos os eventos foram excluidos com exito!");
        }
    }
}
```

As duas *queries* são `TRUNCATE`, se eu coloco uma vai normalmente mais se eu coloco duas da erro no programa e fecha.

Como posso executar 2 *queries* ou mais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está executando apenas uma *query* mesmo, você pode executar mais de um de comando nela, desde que eles sejam separados com ponto e vírgula:

```
public static void excluireventos() {
     using var connection = new SqlConnection(Conn.tank());
     connection.Open();
     using var cmd = new SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Active; TRUNCATE TABLE Active_Number", connection);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     Globals.UpdateLogs("Todos os eventos foram excluidos com exito!");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/TwoCommandsOneQuery.cs).

Dei uma simplificada no código.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente :)

Comment: Só queria acrescentar que, da forma que você fez, se o primeiro comando SQL der algum erro (conflitos de chave estrangeira, por exemplo), o segundo comando ainda vai ser executado, como se nada tivesse acontecido. Já tive uns problemas por causa disso e desde então passei a usar a classe [SqlTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VítorMartins bem observado.